# How to delete space between rows when using rows in Slick?

Tags: css, slick.js

I searched on the Internet and see this demo but I cannot delete distance between rows: https://jsfiddle.net/gdqwn1je/2/

```
$('.slider').slick({
infinite: true,
speed: 300,
prevArrow: false,
nextArrow: false,
rows: 2,
slidesToShow: 4,
responsive: [
  {
    breakpoint: 768,
    settings: {
      rows: 1,
      slidesToShow: 1
    }
  }
]
});
```

Comment: add `vertical-align:top` to your span containing image

Comment: Thanks. It works, sorry for responding too late.